# Pipenv package hash does not match lock file

Tags: python, gunicorn, pypi, pipenv

We have a lock file which has not changed since April 2021. Recently, we have started seeing the following error on `pipenv install --deploy`:

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    gunicorn==20.1.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/dd/5b190393e6066286773a67dfcc2f9492058e9b57c4867a95f1ba5caf0a83/gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (from -r /tmp/pipenv-g7_1pdnq-requirements/pipenv-d64a8p6k-hashed-reqs.txt (line 32)):
        Expected sha256 e0a968b5ba15f8a328fdfd7ab1fcb5af4470c28aaf7e55df02a99bc13138e6e8
             Got        9dcc4547dbb1cb284accfb15ab5667a0e5d1881cc443e0677b4882a4067a807e
```

We have opened an issue in the project GitHub https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2889

We believe that it would be unsafe to use this new version without confirmation it is correct and safe in case someone has maliciously updated the package in the package repository.

Is there a way we can grab the wheel file from a previous docker build and force that to be used for the time being so we can safely build with the existing version and checksum?

Thanks

Comment: That's concerning as [the repo](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/releases) hasn't had a release since April 2021 either. PyPI says it was last updated March 2021. Barring bad actors, there's always network, storage, and memory corruption. I would check to see if you can get the file with the correct sha256 hash using a different computer on a different network. The url is in the error message. Download it directly, run a relevant hashing tool on it, and compare the results with the expected hash in the error.

Comment: @Ouroborus all local machine, build servers and docker containers report the same hash change. What do you mean by running a hashing tool on it?

Comment: There's software that just produces hashes of files. sha256 is a hashing algorithm and is broadly supported. I just ran it on my end and I also get the new hash (`9d...`). I'm not sure what to make of that. There's no good reason for it to have changed.

Comment: `e0...` is for the .tar.gz (source) package, `9d...` is for the .whl package. (See the "view hashes" links on PyPI's [gunicorn files page](https://pypi.org/project/gunicorn/#files)) I'm not sure why your systems are choosing to download the wheel now when they downloaded the source previously. However, those are both valid hashes for that module and version.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks for providing that information. I'd love to mark it as the accepted answer if you'd like to post it as one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ouroborus for the answer:

`e0...` is for the .tar.gz (source) package, `9d...` is for the .whl package. (See the "view hashes" links on PyPI's gunicorn files page) I'm not sure why your systems are choosing to download the wheel now when they downloaded the source previously. However, those are both valid hashes for that module and version.